# How to set printer ACLs in .net?

Tags: .net, security, printing, acl

How do you set a printers ACLs in .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unmanaged function [SetPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145082%28VS.85%29.aspx) with level 3 ([PRINTER_INFO_3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162846%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/com-version-setacl-ocx/) (free), which is available in two versions: command line (EXE) and COM object (OCX). I'd recommend the latter for calls from another program.